# How to set binding context to another assembly in XAML? Type not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin/XAML and am trying to incorporate it into my project, but I'm getting "Type not found" errors when I try to put the BindingContext into the XAML, but it works if I set it in the C# constructor. Any ideas?

**ProjectX.Forms.MainPage.cs**

```
namespace ProjectX.Forms
{
  public partial class MainPage
  {
    public MainPage( )
    {
      InitializeComponent( );
      //this.BindingContext = new ProjectX.ViewModel.MainPage( );
    }
  }
}
```

**ProjectX.Forms.Mainpage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ProjectX.ViewModel;assembly=projectx.viewmodel"
             x:Class="ProjectX.Forms.MainPage"
             Title="Project">
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModel:MainPage/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Input, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Output}"
           Font="Large"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="Center">
    </Label>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**ProjectX.ViewModel.MainPage.cs**

```
namespace ProjectX.ViewModel
{
  public class MainPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

As is, I get the following error message:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:6. Type viewModel:MainPage not found in xmlns clr-namespace:ProjectX.ViewModel;assembly=projectx.viewmodel
```

If I uncomment the comment in ProjectX.Forms.MainPage and remove the BindingContext stuff from the xaml file, the error goes away.

What's the best way to do this using XAML without having to put the bindingcontext in the constructor?

Comment: Do you have a ViewModel folder or you just have a ProjectX.ViewModel project name?

Comment: These are separate projects in the same solution, Forms referencing ViewModel as an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the Name of the Assembly where the MainViewModel resides `projectx.viewmodel`? You can check that in the Project Properties.
2. It's confusing that the Page has the same name as the ViewModel. And it is impractical as you see, since you always have to reference it with the namespace (it's practice to name the ViewModel something like `MainViewModel`)

Comment: 1. The (Name) is camelcase, but the identity and filename are in lowercase.

2. If I change the name of the view (say to MainPage2) I still have this problem.

Comment: I think the problem is with 'clr-namespace:ProjectX.ViewModel;assembly=projectx.viewmodel'. If you followed convention and the MainViewModel resides in an own assembly it should be 'clr-namespace:ProjectX.ViewModel;assembly=ProjectX.ViewModel'. You need to check the assembly name of your ViewModel project in the project's properties (Right-Click Project in Solution Explorer > Properties > Application Tab > Assembly Name)

Comment: I made a new project without any case anomalies today and have still the same problem, even used different class names but no dice. I think I'll have to settle for using the constructor approach for now.